# Log Return calculation for each day in each column in a Dynamic Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Dynamic Named Ranges - HDaCClose and HDaCReturns.

In DNR HDaCClose I have multiple columns with daily close prices of financial instruments for 100 days, thus 100 rows and X columns, see below.

[image: HDaCClose]

For the DNR HDaCReturns I need to calculate  the Natural Log of returns by using the following formula: LN = n/(n - 1). In essence I need the Natural Log of today's Closing price, divided by yesterday's closing price.

[image: HDaCReturns]

I tried to get the logic of looping trough each cell in a column and performing the calculations, before moving to the calculations for each cell in the next column.

The output that I got from it is:

[image: OUTPUT]

Obviously inaccurate...

What should be the correct approach for a loop through each cell in each column in range HDaCReturns and perform the calculations, that I need?

Comment: Post your code, and a screenshot showing some expected results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to know from another of your questions that you can use .FormulaR1C1 to assign the formula to the correct range of cells without need for a loop.  The last row would be excluded from the output calculation as has no row to compare with.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandCalculations").Range ("HDaCReturns")
    .Offset(2, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 3, .Columns.Count - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=LN(R[-103]C/R[-102]C)"
End With
```

The R[-103]C/R[-102] part of the formula references the Closed Values in the current context. You might be able to replace this with a named range reference.

A really verbose way of looking at it would be as follows, where you work with the named ranges and use a array formula (`.FormulaArray`) to do the calculation:

```
Sub AddLnCalcs()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim returnRange As Range
    Dim closeRange As Range
    Dim closedRangeData As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandCalculations")
    Set returnRange = ws.Range("HDaCReturns")
    Set closeRange = ws.Range("HDaCClose")

    With closeRange

        Set closedRangeData = .Offset(2, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 3, .Columns.Count - 1) '.Address 'offset 2 to avoid headers of e.g. EURUSD and close and resize to exclude headers and last row and exclude date column

    End With

    Dim formulaOutputArea As Range

    With returnRange

        Set formulaOutputArea = .Offset(2, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 3, .Columns.Count - 1)
        formulaOutputArea.FormulaArray = "=LN(" & closedRangeData.Address & "/" & closedRangeData.Offset(1, 0).Address & ")"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great one! Thank you!